# share keyboard and mouse in barrier between my windows machine and ubuntu 18.04.1LTS

Tags: keyboard, mouse, sharing

I want to share a keyboard and mouse between two computers. One running windows, the other with Ubuntu (18.04). Since Synergy is paid software, I want to use Barrier.

It was quiet easy to download from:
https://alternativeto.net/software/barrier/

Windows should run the server,
Ubuntu will run the client.

Here is the file to be downloaded for the windows as well as opensource but I've tried to install on opensource that is my ubuntu 18.04 machine it was even installing as client and important to note here I to use windows as a server which I have got that but ubuntu as client is not working properly so please can any one help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: What steps did you follow to install barrier? Please add any error messages or output from Barrier's log to your question.